# iBeaconResult doesn't return array of beacon objects

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ibeacon

For an Ionic project I try to scan for iBeacons on an Android device. The sample code I use is the same as described in the documentation, except the UUID and the identifier (I checked those and they look correct).

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ibeacon/

```
delegate.didEnterRegion()
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('didEnterRegion: ', data);
    }
  );

let beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion('deskBeacon','F7826DA6-ASDF-ASDF-8024-BC5B71E0893E');

this.ibeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion)
  .then(
    () => console.log('Native layer received the request to monitoring'),
    error => console.error('Native layer failed to begin monitoring: ', error)
  );
```

It all looks like its working well as it reach the didEnterRegion() with the following data:

```
eventType: "didEnterRegion"
region:
  identifier: "my_identifier"
  typeName: "BeaconRegion"
  uuid: "my_id"
```

The only problem is that the return value (IBeaconPluginResult) is not the same as described in the documentation (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/ibeacon/#IBeaconPluginResult), as its missing the array of beacons.

Also I implemented the didRangeBeaconsInRegion delegate, but it never reaches the callback.

```
 delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
          .subscribe(
              data => console.log('didRangeBeaconsInRegion: ', data),
              error => console.error()
          );
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

edit:
I also downloaded the Locate Beacon app from the Google Play Store which detects the beacon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. Looking at it now in the morning and feeling stupid that I used the method "startMonitoringForRegion" instead of startRangingBeaconsInRegion...